# Approximation of continuous functions by functions continuous with Compact support

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Can we approximate a function $f\in\mathcal C_0 (\mathbb R^q)$ (continuous function with limit equal $0$ in infinity) get equipped with the supremum norm by a function $g\in\mathcal C_c(\mathbb R^q)$ (function continuous with a compact support) also get equipped with the supremum norm ?

In other word : $\forall f\in\mathcal C_0 (\mathbb R^q),\ \ \forall\epsilon>0, \ \ \exists?g\in\mathcal C_c (\mathbb R^q), \parallel f-g \parallel_\infty <\epsilon$

If it is possible what is the argument for doing that ? Stone-Weierstrass ? References are welcomed.

Comment: What norm are you using? The supremum norm?

Comment: Yes I've just corrected

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this in a simple way:

For each $R>0$ pick a continuous function $f_R$ such that $0 \leq f \leq1; f=1$ on $B_R(0)$ and $f=0$ outside $B_{R+1}(0)$.

Now, show that for each $g \in C_0(\mathbb R^d)$ you have
$$\lim_{R \to \infty} f_R \cdot g =g$$
and $f_R \cdot g \in C_C(\mathbb R^d)$.

Comment: Just about notation : $B_R(0)$ is the closed ball centered in $0$ with radius $R$ ?

Comment: @the-owner Yes. Or the open ball, it makes no difference for the proof.

Comment: Another question : On $B_{R+1}(0)\cap B_{R}(0)$ is it important/crucial for $f_R$ to be in $[0,1]$ as you have written ? and why ?

Comment: @the-owner It is important for these functions to be (equi-) bounded. Otherwise, $f_R\cdot g -g$ could be very large in this region, and this would make $\| f_R\cdot g -g \|_\infty$ large. But as long as there exists some constant $C$ such that $|f_R| \leq C$ everything works.

Comment: you have not specified if $f_R$ is continuous : Means it works if $f_R$ is discontinuous in the borders of the $B_R(0)$ for example ?

Comment: ... means there is no problem in this case with the compactness ?

Comment: The $f_R$ here should be continuous. This is one way to mollify a function, but it is less powerful than mollification by convolution (which can give you derivatives). But you don't need derivatives here, so this is fine.

Comment: Yea, continuity requirement is obviously needed :D @the-owner

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the supremum norm, that's not that complicated. Given $f$ and $\epsilon>0$, choose $M$ such that if $|x|>M$ then $|f(x)|<\epsilon/2$. Introduce $g_0=f 1_{|x| \leq M}$. $g_0$ is compactly supported but not continuous. Now use a standard mollifier to find a function $g$ which is uniformly within $\epsilon/2$ of $g_0$ but which is continuous. $g$ will have a slightly larger support than $g_0$ but still a compact support.

Comment: "Now use a standard mollifier to find a function $g$ which is uniformly" you mean find a sequence $g_n$ that tend uniformly to $g$ ?

Comment: @the-owner You don't really need the full sequence; the function you're looking for is an element of such a sequence, however. (What I'm describing here is not really any different than the other answer, by the way.)

Comment: But don't we need $g_0$ to be continuous on the $M$-borders if we want $g_0$ compactly supported ?

Comment: ... because on $\mathbb R^n$ every compact are bounded & closed ?

Comment: The support of $g_0$ is the intersection of the support of $f$ and the ball $|x| \leq M$. The intersection is closed, and it is contained in a ball, so it's bounded, so the whole thing is compact.

Comment: but in your answer it is not clear if $f$ is any function or a continuous one ? with compactly supported ?

Comment: $f$ is the given function in $C_0$. Its support is closed but typically not compact. But the intersection of a closed set with a compact set is compact. Thus the support of $g_0$ is compact.

Comment: You've said that $g_0$ is not continuous. However can we say, more precisely,  that $g_0$ is not continuous only on $\pm M$ ?

Comment: Well, $|x|=M$ is a sphere, not two points. But yes, that's correct.